# How to make bootstrap rows cleaner?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

[example of the messiness](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrIWY.png)

These items in the rows all have various heights and are drawn in from a database. I would like my page to stay mobile friendly, but make the rows look more clean like this (each 'o' signifies one of the store items):

o o o o

o o o o

if the screen shrank in size it may look like this:

o o o

o o o

o o

or this

o o

o o

o o

o o

Is bootstrap not the best tool for this type of styling? or should i just use css with a load of media queries?  **I think I would just need for the height of each row to be as big as the height of the largest item in the row.** how would i do this using bootstrap (if possible)? Thanks in advance!

Comment: add a `min-height` value to the items

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the default margins and padding.

```
<div class="col-md-4" style="padding:0; margin:0"></div>
```

Or make them whatever you want to be. You can also use the inspector to find the elements you want to change and put them in your css file to override.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this section](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed-complete) in the bootstrap manual. It describes how to do exactly what you want.

It uses a div with class `clearfix visible-xs-block` that is only visible for xs devices after 12 xs columns. This clears the float so that subsequent columns won't be affected by varying heights. Here is another example:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3"></div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3"></div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3"></div>
<div class="clearfix visible-sm-block">
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3"></div>
<div class="clearfix visible-md-block">
```

Notice after 12 sm columns i add `<div class="clearfix visible-sm-block">` which will clear the sm columns and after 12 md columns I add `<div class="clearfix visible-md-block">` which will clear the md columns.